# Why can't I see new NIC with nmtui on CentOS 8 and how to resolve?

Tags: centos, virtualbox, network-interface, networkmanager

**In a nutshell:**

I cannot see my newly added NIC with `nmtui` on CentOS 8. 
How can I resolve this?

**Detail:**

I've installed a CentOS 8 VM on VirtualBox.

Usually I configure two NICs during the installation:

- One as NAT so it can connect to the outside network
- The other as Host Only so I can access it with internal IP

I didn't use Bridged network for I don't want to expose those VMs to the outside world.

It works well for all my VMs.

But when installing a new server I forgot to set a second NIC on VirtualBox during the OS installation, so I added a new NIC in VirtualBox after the installation.

Now I'm able to see the the newly added NIC with both `ip addr`:

```
[root@cent8-4 ~]# ip addr
1: lo: ...
2: enp0s3: /*My working NIC*/ <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:de:33:18 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s3
       valid_lft 84236sec preferred_lft 84236sec
    inet6 ...
3: enp0s8: /*The newly added NIC*/ <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:a7:c7:56 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: virbr0: ...
5: virbr0-nic: ...
```

and `nmcli device`:

```
[root@cent8-4 ~]# nmcli device
DEVICE      TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION
enp0s3      ethernet  connected     enp0s3  /*My working NIC*/
virbr0      bridge    connected     virbr0
enp0s8      ethernet  disconnected  --      /*The newly added NIC*/
lo          loopback  unmanaged     --
virbr0-nic  tun       unmanaged     --
```

Note that enp0s3 is the NIC that I configured during the installation,
while enp0s8 is the one that I added after the installation.

But when I use `nmtui` to configure the IP address of the newly added NIC,
I just can't see it in "Edit a connection" screen:

[image: "Edit a connection" screen]

Neither can I see it in "Activate a connection" screen:

[image: "Activate a connection" screen]

So how can I make `nmtui` recognize this new NIC?

Some articles say that I have to use "auto enp0s8" to initialize the NIC,
but it seems that CentOS 8 doesn't have that tool:

```
[root@cent8-4 network-scripts]# auto enp0s8
bash: auto: command not found...
```

Comment: can you please 'sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager' and check again?!

Comment: I did a network search for “auto enp0s8”, and most of the top ten results were in non-English languages, which is a bad sign. But the ones that *were* in English, like [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/778392/325633#778679 "“Install second network interface on virtualized Ubuntu Server” (on the “Ask Ubuntu” Stack Exchange site)"), indicate that “`auto enp0s8`” is ***a line that you’re supposed to add to* `/etc/network/interfaces`**, not a command that you’re supposed to type into the shell.

Answer (score 1):

1. `cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`
2. `cp ifcfg-enp0s3 ifcfg-enp0s8`
3. change the setting in `ifcfg-enp0s8` (NAME=enp0s8, DEVICE=enp0s8)
4. `systemctl restart NetworkManager`

Answer (score 1):

1. `nmcli device set <device name> managed yes`
2. `nmtui <device name>`

Answer (score 0):

In NetworkManager you configure and activate connection profiles. A profile is a bunch of settings for configuring a device/interface.

Create a new profile for the device and activate it. You can do that with nmtui or another NetworkManager client application of your choice (like nmcli or nm-connection-editor).

See also `nmcli device` vs. `nmcli connection`.